# DRF Pagination page_size not working with ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

I am trying to use ModelViewSet and PageNumberPagination together but can't seem to get page_size working. I have set my size to 200 but it lists 200+ items always.

Here is my code snippet:

```
class ExamplePagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
       page_size = 200
       max_page_size = 200

class VideosViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, JSONParser)
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    pagination_class = ExamplePagination
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    
    @swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: VideoSerializer})
    def list(self, request):
        """
        Request to list all videos
        """
        queryset = Video.objects.all().order_by("-published_at")
        if queryset.exists():
            page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            if page is not None:
                serialized = VideoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                return self.get_paginated_response(serialized.data)
        return Response(status=http_status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I tried everything from custom mixins to setting the page size in settings.py
Here is my settings.py as well

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination",
    'PAGE_SIZE': 200,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass to the serializer `page` instead of `queryset`:

```
    if queryset.exists():
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serialized = VideoSerializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serialized.data)
    return Response(status=http_status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

`queryset` contains all objects, while `page` already contains only required count of objects.

Comment: Hey, this did not solve the issue. I am still getting a count of 339 videos in a request where I should be getting 200.

Comment: @RugvedSomwanshi if you mean count you see in the response, it's ok. Since paginated response always returns information about the total count of objects. It allows the frontend to understand how many pages show on the UI.

Comment: Thank you so much. Understood it perfectly.